# how to set list elements count 0.Is there any way

Tags: java, netbeans

This is my GUI

[image]

And I wanted to load details after clicking load button...So I typed the following code:

```
private void loadActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        DefaultListModel lb=(DefaultListModel)lb1.getModel();
        String sql="Select distinct atomicnumber from properties;";
        try
        {
            Class.forName("java.sql.Driver");
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/elements","root","shanu45");
            Statement s=con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=s.executeQuery(sql);
            while(rs.next())
            {
                int atomicnumber=rs.getInt(1);
                lb.addElement(atomicnumber);
                lb1.setModel(lb);
            }
            rs.close();
            s.close();
            con.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,e.getMessage());
        }
```

But when I clicked it again the values were reloaded
So is there any method for setting list count back to zero for reloading the values?

Comment: Please read ASAP the [tour], the [help] and [ask] then come back and post a valid [mcve] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/). Your time isn't more important than ours, please avoid the use of **ALL BOLD CAPS** text and things like *PLZ ans ASAP!!*, since it will cause people not wanting to help you.

Answer (score 2):

`lb.removeAllElements()` invoked before the while?

Comment: my bad, I mean `removeAllElements()`, fixing the answer

Answer (score 2):

You are not clearing the previously added items to the list. That's why it is reloaded again. All you need to do is to remove the previously added items before running the query again. You can do that by adding **lb.removeAllElements()** before the while loop